# Can my query using join and a subquery be simplified?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, subquery

By some googling, reflecting and try&error I created this query:

```
SELECT sq.movie_id,
       sq.movie_title,
       sq.number,
       sq.movie_year,
       coords.loc_country
FROM   (SELECT Count(*)            AS `number`,
               `coords`.`id_movie` AS movie_id,
               `movie`.`title`     AS movie_title,
               `movie`.`year`      AS movie_year
        -- possibly more info about the movie
        FROM   `coords`
               LEFT JOIN `movie`
                      ON `movie`.`id` = `coords`.`id_movie`
        GROUP  BY `coords`.`id_movie`
        ) AS sq
LEFT JOIN coords ON coords.id_movie = sq.movie_id
ORDER  BY sq.number DESC, sq.movie_title ASC
```

It seems to be fairly complex to me and my question is: Can it be simplified?
The table `movie` contains information like year, title, genre etc. As there is more than one location
for each movie, the locations are kept in another table named `coords`. The objective of the query above is:
Get the number of locations for each movie and additionally the locations themselves and order the
results by the number.

Update: In order to clarify the objective of this query, this is the result after some post processing:

```
array(632) {
  [881]=>
  array(4) {
    ["movie_title"]=>
    string(20) "Eddie Izzard: Circle"
    ["movie_year"]=>
    string(4) "1984"
    ["number"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["drehorte"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Brazil"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "Kenya"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Ukraine"
      [3]=>
      string(4) "Peru"
      [4]=>
      string(11) "Philippines"
      [5]=>
      string(8) "Slovenia"
    }
  }
  [171]=>
  array(4) {
    ["movie_title"]=>
    string(5) "Torso"
    ["movie_year"]=>
    string(4) "1923"
    ["number"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["drehorte"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "Philippines"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "Vietnam"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "China"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "Japan"
      [4]=>
      string(4) "Peru"
      [5]=>
      string(8) "Colombia"
    }
  }
  [266]=>
  array(4) {
    ["movie_title"]=>
    string(24) "Anton Chekhov's The Duel"
    ["movie_year"]=>
    string(4) "1939"
    ["number"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["drehorte"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "China"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Brazil"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "Russia"
      [3]=>
      string(14) "Czech Republic"
      [4]=>
      string(6) "Mexico"
    }
  }
```

Some data related to each movie and an array or list of the location (drehorte).
Code of the postprocessing:

```
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$resultArr = [];
$movieId = -1;
while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
    if ($row->movie_id != $movieId) {
        $movieId = $row->movie_id;
        $resultArr[$movieId] = [
            'movie_title' => $row->movie_title,
            'movie_year' => $row->movie_year,
            'number' => $row->number,
            'drehorte' => [],
        ];
    }
    $resultArr[$movieId]['drehorte'][] = $row->loc_country;
}
```

Comment: Order by without top/limit not at the outer level has no effect. Tables have no row order, result sets [sic] do. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: This query doesn't make much sense. coords left join movie includes having a result row for every coord whether or not it has associated movies--?? Then left join with coord must have the same effect as inner join with coord, so why left?? Your "objectives" suggests movie left join coord (with count(*) giving 1 for unmatched movies). When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.  [Learn how to build relational queries.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for your hints, I agree that sorting in the inner query is obsolete und will remove it. It's just a relict from my first step: Building the subquery on it's own. Regarding left vs. inner join: I'm still a newbie at mysql. Have to dive into the types of join in detail.
>When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

I don't understand this.

Comment: Re "When giving ..." I mean give each table's characteristic predicate per the link I gave.